# What is the best way to execute a single value MDX query in Excel cell?

Tags: vba, mdx, excel-2010

What is the best way to execute a single value MDX query in Excel cell?

VBA is fine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, best way is clear and understandable query syntax. Here is an [example](http://msmvps.com/blogs/xldynamic/archive/2010/09/29/does-excel-do-mdx.aspx).

It is unlikely event, that you just need 1 value. But if that is the case, then any well readable query, that returns the result, will do - you just need to do it once, so why would you care :P

If in fact you need to do whole column, then even how you inserting them in VBA makes quite a big impact. This is because every cell is an object, and it takes time to refer to that object properties.